# Exception in thread django-main-thread:

Tags: django

a lot of time I dont enter to my project.
and when I open it that what I get:

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\Lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\Lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\4\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\4\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 139, in inner_run
    ipv6=self.use_ipv6, threading=threading, server_cls=self.server_cls)
  File "C:\4\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 203, in run
    httpd = httpd_cls(server_address, WSGIRequestHandler, ipv6=ipv6)
  File "C:\4\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 67, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\Lib\socketserver.py", line 452, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\Lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 50, in server_bind
    HTTPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\Lib\http\server.py", line 139, in server_bind
    self.server_name = socket.getfqdn(host)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\Lib\socket.py", line 676, in getfqdn
    hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

before the code work excellent

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I recommend taking the tour and reading through How to Ask and related help topics. Questions seeking debugging help should include a minimal reproducible example, your expectations (what should happen) and where your code, etc. falls short of that. This information (including error messages, etc.) should be included as text with images optionally used to add clarity. –

Answer (score 1):

It's the Python trying to get the host (your computer) name. Did you change it recently? It looks like `utf-8` can not decode it.

Comment: yes. I change it to hebrew. I try to change it back

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I noticed that I have created a new Virtual Environment accidentally, so I deleted the new Vnev folder and It has fixed.